# OpenLayers draw line string with line width in meters

Tags: openlayers-3

Want to draw Line string with line width measured in meters

Tried styles but they are fixed width(in pixels) and don't change line thickness while zooming

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anybody is interested:

```
function() {
    return [
        new ol.style.Style({
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
                width: 50 / ol.map.getView().getResolution()
            })
        })
    ]
}
```

You can provide a function which returns a `ol.style.Style` instead of using a `ol.style.Style` directly (e.g. with `setStyle`).

This function is called within every single render process and you can change the width of a `ol.style.Stroke` dynamically.

In the case above a line is drawn, where the width [should](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242545/how-can-epsg3857-be-in-meters) represent 50 meters in the real world if you use the Web Mercator projection (EPSG:3857).

Answer (score 0):

Try use Polygon, or after drawend change Line to Polygon.